# Adding a formula to a cell with a function gives error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to add a formula to a cell with a function, I want to add
`=unpivot(copyColumns("Elements!A,B,C,D,E",1),2,1,"New","New2")`

but there are quotes in the formula and I keep getting errors because of them.

I am trying `\` which from searching is suppose to work

Thanks

```
 function iSetFormula_n(){

 iSetFormula('Elements',"A1","=unpivot(copyColumns(\"Elements!A,B,C,D,E\",1),2,1,"\New\","\New2\")");
```

}

```
function iSetFormula(shtName, rCell, myFormula) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(shtName);
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var cell = sheet.getRange(rCell);
cell.setFormula(myFormula);
}
```

Comment: in javascript, you can use `'` and `"` interchangeably (in pairs of cours)

Comment: There is a typo, the code says `"\New\"` but should be `\"New\"`. The same for New2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about these modifications?

#### Modification points :

- For `"\New\"` and `"\New2\"` of `"=unpivot(copyColumns(\"Elements!A,B,C,D,E\",1),2,1,"\New\","\New2\")"`, they can modify to `\"New\"` and `\"New2\"`.
- When you use `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(shtName);`, an error occurs at `var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];`.

  - Since you use `shtName`, `var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];` can be removed.

The modified script which reflected above is as follows.

#### Modified script :

```
function iSetFormula_n(){
 iSetFormula("Elements","A1","=unpivot(copyColumns(\"Elements!A,B,C,D,E\",1),2,1,\"New\",\"New2\")"); // Modified
}

function iSetFormula(shtName, rCell, myFormula) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(shtName);
  var cell = ss.getRange(rCell); // Modified
  cell.setFormula(myFormula);
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify.

Comment: Tanaike, Thank you again for your help